terraform - why does my simple terraform for loop give an error?
I created a simple for loop to filter out some elements. I only want elements having ${app.swid} equals ${local.cmpgdb_swid}.
locals {
  cmpgdb_swid = "cmpgdb"
  cmpgdb_path = "pg"
  cmpgdb_prefix = "cmpgdb-pg-"
  cmpgdb_dbadmin = "-pguser-dbadmin"
  cmpgdb_dbowner = "-pguser-dbowner"

  filtered_apps = { 
    for app in local.yaml_data : "${app.swid}.${app.instance}" => app 
    if ${app.swid} == ${local.cmpgdb_swid}
  }
}

Error Messages

Line No 10 = "if ${app.swid} == ${local.cmpgdb_swid}"
Does anyone have a hint on this error?

Hi @mzwettler, welcome to SO :-) Please edit your post and paste the error messages as text.

Where is the yaml_data ?

I'm going to take some liberties and create a yaml_data with something we can loop over...
Here is my code:
locals {
  cmpgdb_swid = "cmpgdb"
  yaml_data = {
    foo = { swid = "asd", instance = 1 }
    bar = { swid = "cmpgdb", instance = 1 }
  }

  filtered_apps = {
    for app in local.yaml_data : "${app.swid}.${app.instance}" => app
    if app.swid == local.cmpgdb_swid
  }
}

output "test" {
  value = local.filtered_apps
}

The difference in my loop is that i'm not doing any interpolation ${variable} in the if, we are not concatenating anything there, no reason to use that there.
... and that works fine, the output when we do a terraform plan is:
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = {
      + "cmpgdb.1" = {
          + instance = 1
          + swid     = "cmpgdb"
        }
    }


You are right. It has been the interpolation in the if. Argh. Blinded by the night. Thanks a lot, Max

@mzwettler if the answer solves your problem don't forget to upvote and accept it as correct, that is the gray check on the left

Terraform does not have if/else statements like languages. They have conditional expressions and it looks more like an inline if statement. Eg:
var.x == 1 ? true : false

That probably the root cause of your error. To achieve a filter on a list you could do something like the below using count (please note this is without knowing exactly what your "local.yaml_data" looks like and guessing you want to create if your condition is true) :
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each = {for data in local.yaml_data : prop => data}

  count = data == ${local.cmpgdb_swid} ? 1 : 0
}

The above demonstrates how you could create a resource conditionally and how to handle a conditional action. Removing your "if" statement will resolve your error. More information here : https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals

You cannot use count and for_each in the same resource.

this feels like an AI hallucination  ... Yes terraform allows if statement in the for loops, https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#filtering-elements ... you can copy my code an run terraform plan it works ... and this question did not mentioned anything about resource, why jump into that?

Oops! my bad, did not know that there was an actual expression. Remember coming across this a while back and was told there is no if statement. Sorry for the misinformation
